# Higgs boson mass and electroweak energy scale

Tags: mass, higgs, electroweak

Is it a coincidence that the mass of the [Higgs boson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson) is exactly half the [electroweak energy scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_scale)?

Comment: Hi Maura, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! We prefer that each separate question should be asked on its own, so I removed the extra thing you were asking about the Higgs and its antiparticle. Feel free to post that as a separate question (if it hasn't been asked on the site already).

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly half. The physical Higgs mass is something around 125 or 126 GeV, but the EW scale is a little less than twice that.

There is a relationship of sorts between the two values, though: the Higgs field $\phi$ is subject to a potential of the form

$$V(\phi) = \mu^2\lvert\phi\rvert^2 + \lambda\lvert\phi\rvert^4$$

Given this potential, the bare mass of the Higgs boson will be $\mu$ and the electroweak energy scale is $\sqrt{-\frac{\mu^2}{\lambda}}$. The relationship depends on the constant $\lambda$.